# Title : self signing server certificate

Tags: android, web-services, https, x509certificate

I need to use “https:\ “  post web service in my android application but I am getting error like “non trusted server certificate” .

Is there any solution for this ???

Following is my code .

```
public static String callservice() {



        String response = "";



        HashMap<String, String> valuemap = new HashMap<String, String>();



        valuemap.put("name", "nandlal");

        valuemap.put("date_of_birth", "12-01-1986");

        valuemap.put("gender", "women");

        valuemap.put("user_name", "nandlal80.840947");

        valuemap.put("confirm_password", "qqqq");

        valuemap.put("email", nandlal@dignizant.com);

        valuemap.put("confirm_email", "nandlal@dignizant.com");

        valuemap.put("co_address", "surat");

        valuemap.put("address_information", "surat");

        valuemap.put("postcode", "45454");

        valuemap.put("country", "india");

        valuemap.put("town", "surat");

        valuemap.put("doorcode", "800");

        valuemap.put("language", "English");

        valuemap.put("telephone_home", "840947");

        valuemap.put("telephone_work", "866");

        valuemap.put("cellphone", "56656");

        valuemap.put("skype_name", "myskype");



        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();



        try {



              response = httpRequest

                          .doPost("https://www.buzzador.com/apps/present_software/webservice/index.php?op=Registration1",

                                      valuemap);



              System.out.println("RESPONCE :" + response);



        } catch (Exception e) {

              // TODO Auto-generated catch block

              e.printStackTrace();

              System.out.println("ERROR :" + e.toString());

              response = e.toString();

        }

        return response;



  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the certificate is self-signed, it is not trusted by the android default trust manager. You can follow the Bob Lee tutorial *[Android: Trusting SSL certificates](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html)* aiming to trust your server certificate in the application: